# How to get the text value out of a radio button list

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

So I have two group boxes, what I am wanting is to get the selected radio button value from both of them.

If it was just a text box you can go:

```
thisValue = textbox1.text
```

But I have no idea how to do it for a radio button

Comment: What class are you actually dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

To get the value (assuming that you want the *value*, not the text) out of a radio button, you get the `Checked` property:

```
bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
```

There is no code-based relation between the radio buttons in a `GroupBox` (other than the radio buttons behaving in a manner so that only one of the radio buttons within the same container is checked at a time); your code will need to keep track of which one that is checked.

The simplest way to do this is perhaps to make the radio buttons within a group box all trigger the same event listener for the `CheckedChanged` event. In the event you can examine the `sender` argument to keep track of which one that is currently selected.

Example:

```
private enum SearchMode
{
    TitleOnly,
    TitleAndBody,
    SomeOtherWay
}
private SearchMode _selectedSearchMode;
private void SearchModeRadioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        if (rb == _radioButtonTitleOnly)
        {
            _selectedSearchMode = SearchMode.TitleOnly;
        }
        else if (rb == _radioButtonTitleAndBody)
        {
            _selectedSearchMode = SearchMode.TitleAndBody;
        }
        else
        {
            // and so on
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is WindowsForms Linq example
if it doesn't work exactly you'd get the idea

```
RadioButton rb = null;
RadioButton checkedRB = groupBox1.Controls.FirstOrDefault(
c => (rb = c as RadioButton) != null && rb.Checked) as RadioButton;

if (checkedRB != null)

{
this.Text = checkedRB.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference to same click event trigger

```
private void rb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    thisValue = ((RadioButton)sender).Text;
}
```